# finding the equations for $y = \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1}\frac{x^i}{(3i-2)(3i+1)(3i+4)}$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the equation for tangent, normal, the length of the subtangent and subnormal to the curve given by: $$y = \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1}\frac{x^i}{(3i-2)(3i+1)(3i+4)}$$

And at these points: $(1,\frac{1}{24})$

I would greatly appreciate feedback towards my working out. I can imagine that this could be solved using partial fractions, so if possible, I would highly welcome to see that approach.

my working out:

I simplified the denominator and used $n$ to represent the summand.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^n}{(27n^3+27n^2-18n-8)^2}=\frac{nx^{n-1}(27n^3+27n^2-18n-8)-(81n^2+54n-18)x^n}{(27n^3+27n^2-18n-8)^2}$$

When $n = 1$ then $$\frac{28-117x}{784}$$

Given that the length of subtangent = $\frac{|y|}{|\frac{dy}{dx}|}$
length of subnormal = $|y||\frac{dy}{dx}|$
length of tangent = $|y|\sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}})^2}$
length of the normal = $|y|\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$

When $x = 1$, then the equation is $$\frac{-89}{784}$$

To test this with the subnormal, I should get:

$$\frac{x^n}{(27n^3+27n^2-18n-8)}\cdot -\frac{89}{784}=\frac{1}{(27+27-18-8)}\cdot -\frac{89}{784}=-\frac{89}{21952}$$

Comment: I don't follow this.  What happened to the infinite sum?  It seems like you've dropped all terms but the first.  Why can you do that?  Start by writing down the partial fraction expansion of $\frac1{(3i-2)(3i+1)(3i+4)}$.

Comment: @saulspatz I replaced the sum by $n$, as I wouldn't know how to approach it with an infinite sum. Although, given $i = 1$, then starting with $n = 1$, it seemed easier to understand. I'm not sure what you mean by your other comment, and thanks for the partial fraction suggestion. I'll give it a go.